# minikube recover from unexpected power outages

Tags: minikube

Minikube fail to start after the PC unexpectedly loses power or is kicked:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> minikube.exe start
* minikube v1.2.0 on windows (amd64)
* Tip: Use 'minikube start -p <name>' to create a new cluster, or 'minikube delete' to delete this one.
* Restarting existing virtualbox VM for "minikube" ...
* Waiting for SSH access ...
* Configuring environment for Kubernetes v1.15.0 on Docker 18.09.6
* Relaunching Kubernetes v1.15.0 using kubeadm ...

X Error restarting cluster: waiting for apiserver: timed out waiting for the condition

* Sorry that minikube crashed. If this was unexpected, we would love to hear from you:
  - https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new
* Problems detected in "kube-addon-manager":
  - error: unable to recognize "STDIN": Get https://localhost:8443/api?timeout=32s: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8443: connect: connection refused
  - error: unable to recognize "STDIN": Get https://localhost:8443/api?timeout=32s: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
  - error: unable to recognize "STDIN": Get https://localhost:8443/api?timeout=32s: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8443: connect: connection refused
```

I fell into this accident several times. I had to `minikube delete`, `minikube start`, then redeploy my development environment. This is very troublesome, is there a better solution?

Comment: You should check the VirtualBox VM first. It could fail to boot or wait for some input in the middle of bootup. Have you looked at the VM logs in the vm_name\Logs directory and at the VM console?

Comment: @mebius99 [journalctl.log](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/files/3458209/journalctl.log)

Comment: It seems `kube-apiserver` pod can't start. There is an error "failed to "StartContainer" for "kube-apiserver"". Minikube gave up trying it 5 mins later. I am afraid without running apiserver `kubectl` will not run. Hence there's no way to get pod list and pod events for troubleshooting. You could try: 1) `minikube logs`; 2) find out the list of exited containers with `docker ps -a | grep api`, and then look at the exited container log with `docker logs api_container_id`.